# Custom fields to be displayed via code in woocommerce / dokan

Tags: php, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, dokan

Help would be great with this... pulling my hair out.

So I use a multivendor plugin.( Dokan )

On the vendor add new item page, I would like to have a drop-down with options for them to choose.

Then show that on the product page.

Any way of doing this via php?

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/displaying-custom-field-values-in-your-theme

- I think this would show the drop-down on the product page, but it's the selection on the vendor page I'm having a problem with.

All the best.

Answer (score 0):

I can provide the file location.

Popup form - `wp-content/plugins/dokan-lite/templates/products/tmpl-product-popup.php` file
Edit form - `dokan-lite/templates/products/new-product-single.php` file

You need to modify the Dokan product upload template and then you have to add an extra field by overriding the template. After adding the input filed you have to save the value of the field. On that place you have to use `do_action( 'dokan_new_product_added', $product_id, $post_data );` this hook to save the field data.

When you will edit the product that time you have to use `do_action( 'dokan_product_updated', $post_id );` to re-save.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will have a look at this & let you know :)

Comment: Good, I wrote a new post here- https://nayemdevs.com/how-to-add-a-new-field-on-product-upload-form-dokan-multivendor/